# Edit last element of each line of text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I've got a text file with some elements as such;

```
0,The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python,Kenneth Reitz,2/4/2012,0
1,Harry Potter,JK Rowling,1/1/2010,8137
2,The Great Gatsby,F. Scott Fitzgerald,1/2/2010,0
3,To Kill a Mockingbird,Harper Lee,1/3/2010,1828
```

The last element of these lists determine which user has taken out the given book. If 0 then nobody has it.
I want a code to replace the ',0' of any given line into an input 4 digit number to show someone has taken out the book.

I've used .replace to change it from 1828 e.g. into 0 however I don't know how I can change the last element of specific line from 0 to something else.

I cannot use csv due to work/education restrictions so I have to leave the file in .txt format.

I also can only use Standard python library, therefore no pandas.

Comment: that's a job for `csv` module.

Comment: your data are in CSV, so you should first load it as CSV (using `csv.reader` or `pandas.read_csv`). This will return a data structure which is easy to work with. Do your changes, then write it back to CSV (`csv.writer` or `pandas.to_csv`).

Comment: Should've added to my question: I can not use csv, it has to be in .txt format.

Comment: You can still load it using the `csv` module even as a .txt file.

Comment: This is something I didn't know. I'll do some research on csv and see where I get. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture `txt` using `read_csv` into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv("text_file.txt", header=None)
df.columns = ["Serial", "Book", "Author", "Date", "Issued"]
print(df)
df.loc[3, "Issued"] = 0
print(df)
df.to_csv('text_file.txt', header=None, index=None, sep=',', mode='w+')
```

This replaces the third book issued count to 0.

```
Serial                              Book               Author      Date  \
0       0  The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python        Kenneth Reitz  2/4/2012   
1       1                      Harry Potter           JK Rowling  1/1/2010   
2       2                  The Great Gatsby  F. Scott Fitzgerald  1/2/2010   
3       3             To Kill a Mockingbird           Harper Lee  1/3/2010   

   Issued  
0       0  
1    8137  
2       0  
3    1828  

   Serial                              Book               Author      Date  \
0       0  The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python        Kenneth Reitz  2/4/2012   
1       1                      Harry Potter           JK Rowling  1/1/2010   
2       2                  The Great Gatsby  F. Scott Fitzgerald  1/2/2010   
3       3             To Kill a Mockingbird           Harper Lee  1/3/2010   

   Issued  
0       0  
1    8137  
2       0  
3       0
```

**Edit after comment**:
In case you only need to use python standard libraries, you can do something like this with file read:

```
import fileinput

i = 0
a = 5 # line to change with 1 being the first line in the file
b = '8371'
to_write = []

with open("text_file.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        i += 1
        if (i == a):
            print('line before')
            print(line)
            line = line[:line.rfind(',')] + ',' + b + '\n'
            to_write.append(line)
            print('line after edit')
            print(line)
        else:
            to_write.append(line)
print(to_write)

with open("text_file.txt", "w") as f: 
    for line in to_write:
            f.write(line)
```

File content

```
0,The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python,Kenneth Reitz,2/4/2012,0
1,Harry Potter,JK Rowling,1/1/2010,8137
2,The Great Gatsby,F. Scott Fitzgerald,1/2/2010,84
3,To Kill a Mockingbird,Harper Lee,1/3/2010,7895
4,XYZ,Harper,1/3/2018,258
5,PQR,Lee,1/3/2019,16
```

gives this as output

```
line before
4,XYZ,Harper,1/3/2018,258

line after edit
4,XYZ,Harper,1/3/2018,8371

["0,The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python,Kenneth Reitz,2/4/2012,0\n", '1,Harry Potter,JK Rowling,1/1/2010,8137\n', '2,The Great Gatsby,F. Scott Fitzgerald,1/2/2010,84\n', '3,To Kill a Mockingbird,Harper Lee,1/3/2010,7895\n', '4,XYZ,Harper,1/3/2018,8371\n', '5,PQR,Lee,1/3/2019,16\n', '\n']
```

Comment: This looks like it would work for what I want, however how could I rewrite it back to the txt file once the changes are done?

Comment: Unfortunately I can only use standard python libraries so pandas won't be an option. Frustrating.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, does this solve your issue?

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything, maybe I'm doing something wrong. I will have input 'a' as line to change and 'b' as change value to. for example a=5 and b=8371.

Comment: It works for me. Make sure that your file has at least 5 lines and b should be a string. Please see my code once again, i changed my variables according to yours.

Comment: Perfect. I think I was using a string rather than int. It's working now, with slight adjustment of (a+1) because list starts from 0. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
to_write = []
with open('read.txt') as f:  #read input file
    for line in f:
        if int(line[-2]) ==0:
            to_write.append(line.replace(line[-2],'1234'))  #any 4 digit number
        else:
            to_write.append(line)


with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:  #name of output file
    for _list in to_write:

            f.write(_list)
```